# How to have Spring Integration FTP Message Source produce Message<String> straight to channel, not creating a File

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

**Is it possible to read a file from an FTP message source and send it straight to a channel as a Message<String> with the file contents as the message payload and the filename in a header?  How would I do this?**

Right now, it is writing the file from the FTP source to disk, which I don't want it to do.  I'd then have to read off of the disk and then convert it into a message or write a file source of some sort.  I want it to go straight from the FTP source directly into the channel as a Message<String>.

To explain the situation, I am having multiple FTP sources all polling into a channel as one flow.  I am then wanting all messages in that channel to go to a JdbcOutboundGateway to write the messages to a DB table in another flow.  However, when it gets into the channel from the FTP source, the message payload ends up just being the file path.  I want the FTP message source to not create a file, just a Message<String> and place into the channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check [FTP Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-streaming) documentation?

> The streaming inbound channel adapter was introduced in version 4.3.
>   This adapter produces message with payloads of type `InputStream`,
>   allowing files to be fetched without writing to the local file system.

I think this is exactly what you want. You end up with `Message<InputStream>` in your channel, but you always can transform these into `Message<String>` using message transformers, like [StreamTransformer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/transformer/StreamTransformer.html).